# Is there an easy way to return a success call to $q.all without having to create a $q.defer() variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

My application has a number of synchronous and asynchronous (doing a $http call) methods. In 
the controllers I have code like this:

```
$q.all([
    asyncMethod1(),
    syncMethod1()
])
.then(function (results) {
```

Even though I have no need to wait on the syncMethod1() I put this inside the $q.all to keep things simple and to allow me to 
change the method to async if I wanted in the future.

For the sync functions I am calling them like this:

```
var syncMethod1 = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    var abc = 99;
    defer.resolve({
        data1: abc,
        data2: 123
    });
    return defer.promise;
};
```

What I would like to know is if there's a way that I can have the sync method return to the $q.all the data but without my 
needing to create a defer variable and then do a return of the defer.promise? Just trying to make the sync method as simple
as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#all) can, even if not documented, take plain values as well and not only promises (it will automatically convert them). Your sync method should just do

```
return {
    data1: 99,
    data2: 123
};
```

which is the most simplest thing (and can be used in really synchronous contexts as well).

---

> How can I make a promise from a value without using tedious deferreds?

You can use [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q#when):

```
return $q.when({
    data1: 99,
    data2: 123
});
```

If the value is not already a promise, then a promise will be returned that is resolved with the value as soon as possible. Notice that this will necessarily introduce asynchrony in your code, so it's not really a `syncMethod` any more.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR :** Yes, just return normal values from sync method and use them in `$q.all` as input params. It will handle them correctly.

**Long answer**

If we look into the angular code for `$q.all` we see at [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L495) how input params are handled:

```
 function all(promises) {
     ....
     forEach(promises, function(promise, key) {
         ....
          ref(promise).then(function(value) {
```

So each param is passed to the `ref` function [defined at this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L334). `ref` takes an argument and if it is a promise it returns it

```
 if (value && isFunction(value.then)) return value;
```

if it isn't then the value is wrapped with a new created promise which gets returned. That promise gets resolved as soon as possible but not in this event loop iteration.

```
return {
  then: function(callback) {
    var result = defer();
    nextTick(function() {
      result.resolve(callback(value));
    });
    return result.promise;
  }
};
```

This means you can safely return non promise values form your sync methods.

```
function asyncFirst() {
    var def = $q.defer();

    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.first = true;
      def.resolve();
    }, 1000);

    return def.promise;
}

function syncSecond() {
     $scope.second = true;
    return {
        data1: 'abc',
        data2: 123
    };
}

$q.all([
    asyncFirst(),
    syncSecond()
])
.then(function(){
    $scope.all = true;
});
```

See it in action in [this jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/nugic/2/edit?html,js,output)

EDIT:
  As user @Bergi suggests any regular value could be converted to the promise if needed with `$q.when` [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L421) However, `$q.when` uses the `ref` function to convert value to a promise and resolves the promise at the next event loop iteration. Strictly speaking the method itself is sync as it returns without the delays. But the result is immediately wrapped into the promise and not going to be used until next event loop iteration. This means that the sync method isn't used as such. At least not in a away most people imagine sync methods. The overall result of `$q.all` is going to use such sync methods as async but resolved in the next iteration. Consider this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do a bit more logic than just returning values, and you're doing it for a lot of sync functions, you might want to create a wrapper function that does the deferred logic for you:

```
var makeAsync = function(fn){
 return function(){
   var deferred = $q.defer();       
   deferred.resolve(fn.apply(this,arguments));
   return deferred.promise;
  };
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
$q.all([
    asyncMethod1(),
    makeAsync(syncMethod1)()
])
.then(function (results) {
```