# Promises: q.all() with mixed sync and async functions

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm still learning about Promises and I'm facing a problem. Maybe you can help me.

I have a task which does some checks before running the real stuff. Some of those checks are sync, others are async.

So I'd like to have something like this:

```
q.all([
    jenkins.checkConfig,
    gitlab.checkConfig,
    sonar.checkConfig
])
.then(
    function() {
        doSomethingReallyCoolHere();
    }
);
```

But what if sonar.checkConfig is not a promise ? How can I give it a promise behavior ?

Currently I'm doing this

```
var checkConfig = function() {
    var qChecked = q.defer();

    var isOK = awesomeSyncTestHere();

    if (isOK) {
        qChecked.resolve();
    }
    else {
        qChecked.reject();
    }

    return qChecked.promise;
}
```

But it looks stupid.

I guess that's not the good way to do it, right ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: related: [Is there an easy way to return a success call to $q.all without having to create a $q.defer() variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23780918/1048572) (in angular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with placing non-promise values in the input array to [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall). They will just be treated like a promise that had been fulfilled with them.

However, you need to put actual values (or promises) in the array, not the functions that would return them. Just go for

```
Q.all([
    jenkins.checkConfig(),
    gitlab.checkConfig(),
    sonar.checkConfig()
]).then(doSomethingReallyCoolHere);
```

If you do want your checks to throw (and prevent the `then` callback from running), you will need to return a rejected promise indeed. You shouldn't use a deferred for that, though:

```
function checkConfig() {
    if (awesomeSyncTestHere())
        return Q(true);
    else
        return Q.reject(new Error("awesome fail"));
}
```

or, if you have a test that really `throw`s, just use [`Q.try`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefcallargs)

```
function checkConfig() {
    return Q.try(awesomeSyncTestHere);
}
```